# IEnumerable , C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте , вопрос прост , что не так в следующем коде :

```
public class some_class : IEnumerable<another_class>
{
    private another_class[] class_list;

    IEnumerator<another_class> IEnumerable<another_class>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<another_class>)class_list.GetEnumerator();
    }
...
}
```

Компилятор упорно выдает ошибку : ... не реализуется член интерфейса "System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()"

Не совсем понятно , как можно реализовать метод IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() ведь IEnumerable обобщенный интерфейс и нужно указывать тип коллекции(что я и делал).
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Понимаете в том то и дело : я пробовал реализовать 2-ой метод ,но компилятор сразу красным подчеркивает слово IEnumerator , если не указывать тип T . Наверное нагляднее будет конкретный кусок кода показать :

    public class garage : IEnumerable<Sport_car>
    {
        private Sport_car[] car_list;

        
        IEnumerator<Sport_car> IEnumerable<Sport_car>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator<Sport_car>)car_list.GetEnumerator();
        }
         


        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return car_list.GetEnumerator();
        }
..

Comment: Пишет , что использование универсального типа "System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerator<T>" требует аргумента типа "1" 
То есть нельзя даже просто написать IEnumerator почему-то

Comment: Исправьте `IEnumerator` на `System.Collections.IEnumerator`, либо добавьте соответствующий `using`.

`Inumerator` и `IEnumerator<T>` это разные типы, они находятся в разных пространствах имён, однако второй интерфейс требует реализации первого.

Answer (score 4):

Интерфейс, к-й вы реализуете в свою очередь реализует не типизированный IEnumerable:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}

public interface IEnumerator<out T> : IDisposable, IEnumerator
{
    T Current
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface IEnumerator
{
    object Current
    {
        get;
    }

    bool MoveNext();

    void Reset();
}
```

Следовательно вам необходимо реализовать и его "внутренности", а именно еще один метод GetEnumerator() и IEnumerator<out T>:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GarageEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator enumerator;

    public GarageEnumerator(IEnumerator enumerator)
    {
        this.enumerator = enumerator;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        enumerator.Reset();
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get { return (T)enumerator.Current; }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}

public class Garage<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly T[] carList; //initialization !

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new GarageEnumerator<T>(carList.GetEnumerator());
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

А вообще пользуйтесь встроенными средствами в VS - она может сделать ето за вас.

UPDATE: 
начиная с 3.5 фреймворка можно подключить:

```
using System.Linq;
```

и реализация:

```
public class Garage<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly T[] carList = new T[10]; //initialization !

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return carList.Cast<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```